# Adding field vector layer in QGIS modeler and using it in next steps?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, table, qgis-modeler

I am trying to create a model with QGIS to intersect a polygon layer P with a vector grid G and find the % of P for every cells of G. These are the steps to find this :

1. create grid G with *id* unique field
2. find *GRIDSURF* = cell area
3. intersect grid G with polygon layer P
4. dissolve intersected layer by attribute grid *id*
5. calculate *PSURF* = dissolved polygons area / *GRIDSURF*

My problem with the modeler is that, in step 5, the modeler can't find the field GRIDSURF created in step 2

What I really don't understand, is that in the following model with 2 outputs, the GRIDSURF field (with `$area` formula) is in the **result_grid** output layer, but this same field is not in the layer submitted to INTERSECT ... and I have an error after the DISSOLVE saying that the GRIDSURF field is not found.

Did I miss something ?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Which operation do you perform in the `Select code Ocsol` step?

Comment: @mgri I am selecting a subset of Ocsol layer with a land cover code (criteria : _fld_occup=val_text_) before intersecting it with the grid

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but it seems that everything works for me (but probably I skipped some crucial step). Is it possible to upload your model, preferably also including a sample of your two input layers?